How to send keystrokes to Universal control
For testing purposes, I need to send keystrokes to my iPad. Using Universal control, I am able to press a key with my keyboard connected to my mac and it will register on the iPad. However using an automation tool like osascript to press the key does not register on the ipad. In case anyone is interested, here's the command I'm using:
def press_key(key):
    cmd = "osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" + key + "\"'"
    os.system(cmd)

Any help is appreciated!
